# Outlook -OWA- incorrect “sent to”

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-workspace

I'm having a little issue, I'm forwarding my Google Apps for Business emails to outlook with intermedia as our exchange provider and all mail in one of the outlook web access accounts regardless where it comes from, the "sent to" shows up as a diffrent email, in gmail it shows up the correct "sent to".

(i.e. in gmail we set up forwarding filter that all mail sent from 11@example.com should be forwarded to 22@example.com. so in the gmail inbox of 22@example.com mail that was sent to 11 shows up "sent to" 11 but in the outlook inbox of "22" that same email shows up "sent to" "22" which really was sent to "11")

my end goal is to be able to filter all mail sent to one of the emails to be put in a folder, in gmail it goes to that folder, in outlook it won't.

I'm a newbie in IT and in stack exchange for that matter so please understand.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sender and Recipient are showing that way because forwarding an email (even with a rule in place) passes the message off as a new email, from the original recipient sent to the forwarding address.

I think you're looking to create a transport rule, which occurs at the email server level before the message hits a specific mailbox. Perhaps this help page from Google could provide more info: https://support.google.com/a/answer/77182?hl=en

EDIT: Clarity in first sentence.